# Need a quick jquery solution to capture the current url and inject it into another url link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, social-networking

My brain is fried ATM and I have a looming deadline, I am looking for a way to grab the currently viewed pages url and place it into another link for bookmarking/social links.

```
Facebook link:http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[PAGEURL]
Myspace link:http://www.myspace.com/Modules/PostTo/Pages/?u=[PAGEURL]
Twitter link: http://twitter.com/home?status=Check+this+out:+[PAGEURL]
Stumble Upon link:http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=[PAGEURL]
Digg link: http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url=[PAGEURL]
```

I need to replace [PAGEURL] with the URL for the page being viewed. Any help is most appreciate. i have been looking for a while now and can't seems to find an answer that fits this specific circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd help to see what kind of structure those links are in. But, here's some jQuery that might point you in a good direction. It assumes your social bookmarking links are in a container with `id="socials"`, but you can mash the selector to do whatever it takes to get hold of your social links.

```
$(function() {
    var links = $('#socials a'),
        matchExp = /\[PAGEURL\]/,
        currentURL = location.href;

    links.each(function() {
        var currentHREF = $(this).attr('href');
        if (currentHREF.match(matchExp)) {
            $(this).attr('href',currentHREF.replace(matchExp,currentURL));
        }
    });

});
```

This uses the [attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#name) function to get where the link points to, then a regular expression (eww!) to check if the link has [PAGEURL] in it, and to replace [PAGEURL] with location.href, which is the url of the current page. Here's a [handy regexp tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: @Dan-F 
I know this is a really old post but I love this solution and have used it several times, thank you.  
I am working on a new script and I need the "currentURL" to actually be a href in a specific class. Is that possible?

`currentURL = $('.series a').attr('href');`

Comment: @BostonBB sorry, I'm not really understanding the question. Might be better to start a question and then drop a link here, that way others can help too :-)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would be something like

```
var faceBookUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=" + location.href
```